# Change typing color in Swift TextView

Tags: ios, swift

How to change the color by pressing typing in TextView?

For example, I type in black, and then press the button of color orange and more print text in orange color, then I press on the black button and print black text?

The studied methods can have the color of all typed text or placeholders etc.

Comment: You need to change color of text while typing? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `UITextView`? There is an obvious property you set that defines the attributes of the typed text.

Comment: @rmaddy I believe those properties will change all the text in the field? He appears to be after a way of changing just new text and maintain the format of any existing text.

Comment: @AliBeadle No. Look at `typingAttributes`.

Comment: @rmaddy I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
@IBAction func blackButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let attributedText = textView.attributedText

    textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
}

@IBAction func redButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let attributedText = textView.attributedText

    textView.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
}
```

[image]

You can also achieve this by setting the `typingAttributes` property of the `textView`, which seems to be a nicer solution:

```
@IBAction func redButtonClicked() {
  textView.typingAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.redColor()
}

@IBAction func blackButtonClicked() {
  textView.typingAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Viktor Simkó !!!

Comment: @SashDing You're welcome! You could accept this as the answer, if it has solved your problem.

Comment: This beautiful code decided my problem at all! Thank you!

Comment: @SashDing   Please accept the answer (press the tick).

Comment: Sorry)) I am newbie))

Comment: Changing the `typingAttributes` property of the text view is a neater solution.

Comment: @Abizern Thank You! I've updated my answer.